# How to avoid having to explicitly set HDFS locations of hive partitions?

Tags: hive

we have a hive table that is partitioned on several keys. lets call these keys `country, state, city` for illustration. we add new partitions to this table using following command:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD PARTITION("us", "wa", "seattle") LOCATION "hdfs://root_path/us/wa/city=seattle"
```

this is becoming unscalable for us because for every combination of `(country, state, city)` we are issuing above command. E.g., lets say each of the keys can take 100 different values and so we have total 100 * 100 * 100 = 1e6 combinations and have to issue 1e6 SQL commands like above.

isn't there a way to tell hive in 1 SQL command during the table creation that please look in the directory `hdfs://root_path/{country}/{state}/city={city}` to get the data corresponding to `(country, state, city)`. E.g., to get data for `(canada, bc, vancouver)` just look in `hdfs://root_path/canada/bc/city=vancouver`

Comment: You can set explicitly the `LOCATION` of each partition, instead of relying on the default naming convention. But that still means 1e6 `ALTER TABLE` commands.

Comment: Now, seriously, your 3 partitioning columns are *not* independant; they form a hierarchy. Did you consider creating an single level of partitioning, with an aggregate column formed like `ca:bc:vancouver`, and storing each individual column in Parquet? Or maybe a single level like `ca:bc` while making sure that each file contains only one City so that the Parquet footer statistics allow for immediate file-level pruning? Or the other way around, one level of partitioning but for City, since there not too many collisions?

Answer (score 0):

Check hive dynamic partition [Hive dynamic partition inserts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-DynamicPartitionInserts)

> In the dynamic partition inserts, users can give partial partition
>   specifications, which means just specifying the list of partition
>   column names in the PARTITION clause.

If you had a table based on a file. This will work.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tbl PARTITION (country, state, city)
SELECT
  other1, other2, ...     -- set another columns first
  country, state, city    -- columns for partition are last
FROM source_table WHERE ...
```

Comment: we do not have table based on a file. the data for a (country, state, city) is stored under hdfs://root_path/{country}/{state}/city={city} in a parquet file and the data in this file does NOT have the country, state and city columns.